# polymorphism on models and modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, module, polymorphism

Lets say i have this module:

```
module Template

 def self.included(base)

    base.class_eval do
      before_validation(:on => :create) { sanitize_text! }
    end

    base.extend(ClassMethods)
 end

 module ClassMethods

   def sanitize_text!
     # some stuff
   end

 end

end
```

And then I have a model defined like so:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Template
end
```

Notice that i did not override the method sanitize_text! but when I run through this Rails will give me an error:

undefined method `sanitize_text!' for #

Which i don't understand - isn't it suppose that my model Invitation would have included that method already from the module Template?

Answer (score 2):

The before_validation calls the block as an instance, so there is no sanitize_text! because sanitize_text! is a class method.

Define sanitize_text! in the module, not as a class method.

```
module Template
  ...
  def sanitize_text!
    # some stuff
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've included it as a *Class Method*, not as a method on any specific instance of that model.

To use that you need to call it like:

```
Invitation.sanitize_text!
```

To call it on an instance of Invitation, make these changes:

```
module Template

 def self.included(base)

    base.class_eval do
      before_validation(:on => :create) { sanitize_text! }
    end

    base.extend(ClassMethods)
 end

 def sanitize_text!
   # some stuff
 end

 module ClassMethods
 end

end
```

Then you'll be able to call it on a particular method:

```
@invitation.sanitize_text!
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it you're extending `Invitation` class with method `sanitize_text!`, not the instances of `Invitation`.

If you want instance to have `sanitize_text!`, you should better rename `ClassMethods` to `InstanceMethods` and change `self.included` to have this line:

```
base.send :include, InstanceMethods
```

So the whole code would look like this:

```
module Template
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      before_validation(:on => :create) { sanitize_text! }
    end

    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def sanitize_text!
      # method body
    end
  end
end
```